# Excel VBA if statement outputs only 0 value

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code that I am working with. It is really simple, but still not working as expected.

```
Dim hey As Range
Set hey = Range("A1:A5")

For Each i In hey

If i.Value = "15" Then
i.Offset(0, 2).Value = "15" And i.Offset(0, 3).Value = "15"

ElseIf i.Value = 10 Then
i.Offset(0, 2).Value = "10" And i.Offset(0, 3).Value = "10"

ElseIf i.Value = 5 Then
i.Offset(0, 2).Value = "5" And i.Offset(0, 3).Value = "5"

ElseIf i.Value > 15 And i.Value = "*5" Then
i.Offset(0, 2).Value = "10" And i.Offset(0, 3).Value = "5"

Else: i.Offset(0, 2).Value = 10 And i.Offset(0, 3).Value = 10
End If
Next i
```

Right now, all it will do is offset by 2 columns and output 0. I cannot distinguish why and I am at the end of my mental rope with this. I'm sure it is something retardedly simple I am overlooking.

I've tried stepping through and it looks like it evaluates properly for each value in my sample, but still gives me the 0 value. Also, I was playing around with the quotations to see if that had to do with it, but they are strings I want to work with.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take out your `And` statements outside of the if statements. Break each piece into two lines.

Comment: I'm no VBA expert but your final Else clause is missing apostrophes for the values

Comment: Ok, first it look like a nice place where to use `Select Case` instead of `If`. Second you are mixing numeric values ant text value, are your cells filled with numbers or text? Could you give a sample of inputs? Third, `i.Offset(0, 2).Value = "15" And i.Offset(0, 3).Value = "15"` means put in `i.Offset(0, 2).Value` the result of  ` "15" And i.Offset(0, 3).Value = "15"`, that is probably not what you try to do.

Comment: This question needs clarification on whether the values in the cells are real numbers (e.g. `15`) or text-that-look-like-a-number (e.g. `"15"`). They are **not** the same thing and boolean comparisons may not produce the correct results unless the proper comparison is made.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I mean by removing `And` Statements:

```
Dim hey As range
Set hey = range("A1:A5")

For Each i In hey

If i.Value = "15" Then
i.Offset(0, 2).Value = "15"
i.Offset(0, 3).Value = "15"

ElseIf i.Value = 10 Then
i.Offset(0, 2).Value = "10"
i.Offset(0, 3).Value = "10"

ElseIf i.Value = 5 Then
i.Offset(0, 2).Value = "5"
i.Offset(0, 3).Value = "5"

ElseIf i.Value > 15 And i.Value = "*5" Then
i.Offset(0, 2).Value = "10"
i.Offset(0, 3).Value = "5"

Else
i.Offset(0, 2).Value = 10
i.Offset(0, 3).Value = 10
End If
Next i
```

EDIT:

To a computer program, And is a comparison operator. It does not understand it the exact same way humans do. When discussing with another human, we can give a string of tasks linked together by 'and,' and there will be no confusion on what to do (unless the tasks themselves are confusing!). A computer uses `And` to check if multiple conditions are true at the same time. In your last `Elseif` you properly use this to tell the computer: "Check if `i.Value` > 15 AND Check if `i.Value` = "*5". If BOTH (because of the `And` statement) conditions are true, then run the following code."

Hopefully this helps explain the difference!

EDIT 2:

From @litelite 's suggestion, use the Like operator.

```
ElseIf i.Value > 15 And i.Value Like "*5" Then
i.Offset(0, 2).Value = "10"
i.Offset(0, 3).Value = "5"
```

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to explain to OP what `and` really means.

Comment: Ah yes, I've done this before with the and statement. Logically to me it makes sense, of course, but to the code I remember why that doesn't work out. The code above worked just fine, except for the
    ElseIf i.Value > 15 And i.Value = "*5" Then 
line did not evaluate properly.

Comment: @litelite Thanks for the suggestion, added it in!

Comment: @SsaSnakebite What should that ElseIf do?

Comment: @PartyHatPanda I'm hoping you could help me with one other item. The line I mentioned in my comment:

    ElseIf i.Value > 15 And i.Value = "*5" then

In my sample list, I have the value of 25, which excel is evaluating to 10 and 10, rather than 10 and 5. It seems to be skipping over that line and going straight to the else statement.

The point of the "*5" is to find those values that end in the number 5, and return the values of 10 and 5.

Comment: @SsaSnakebite You cannot use wildcard in equaliity. it will check if there is literraly a star. check out the [like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator

Comment: @litelite Thank you both for the assistance! Now to apply this fix to my larger project. Hopefully it doesn't break anything! Cheers.

Hopefully I can remember how the And operator works next time around.

Answer (score 1):

Just to anwser off the back of @PartyHatPanda. You could use `ElseIf i.Value > 15 And Right(i.Value, 1) = 5 Then`. This Check if `i.value`'s last digit is equal to 5. I this what you want?

Comment: I cant comment sorry but I'm pretty sure that what OP is after

Comment: I used the above suggestions of the Like operator and it works well enough for me!